# Can I password protect an application?

Tags: c++, c, security, macos

I have an application which I don't want people to access unless given explicit permission (via a password). More specifically, this application needs to be "locked" during certain hours of the day unless the user enters a password.

The ability to check the time is simple. The ability to lock the application is what I don't know how to do. The reason that this needs to be done is that the company doesn't trust the user to log out and doesn't want any unauthorized access to the application. This is meant as a sort of last measure just in case.

I didn't write the application though, so I cant embed a password into it. The machine has only one user and I don't want to create others. My user is an admin as well, therefore most options appealing to use of the os to provide security wont work.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? 
I'm dealing with Mac OS X but would prefer an OS independent solution. Any solution involving `C` or `C++` is welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: I would like a question that is not unanswerable. What scenario are you trying to protect against? The way you've constructed your use case, there is no protection for the application. Your user has root, therefore can do anything, including copying the software and giving away the password.

Comment: I dont appreciate you closing a question without giving me a chance to clarify or rephrase. Furthermore, there are things that can be done as suggested by Will0.

Comment: you could use cryptography. Encrypt the application and create a wrapper app (could use the same name and icon) that requests a password and uses it to generate a key to decrypt and launch the application. Just don't leave the decrypted app lying around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about you embed the app in an encrypted disk image bundle? As long as the only user that uses it never copies it from there and properly unmounts the bundle afterwards, i think it would accomplish what you want:

1. Create a new *encrypted* disk image (DMG) using Disk Utility (this allows you to enter a password), store it anywhere within the user's home directory.
2. Mount the DMG and place the app you're trying to protect inside it
3. Create an alias to the app within the mounted DMG and place it on the desktop
4. Unmount the DMG

After that, when the user double-clicks the alias on the desktop, the user is prompted for the DMG's password. If it's correct, the DMG is mounted and the app is started automatically and directly.

To **auto-unmount afterwards** perhaps you could script something that uses the `diskutil` shell command, like this: `> diskutil unmount /Volumes/DMG_NAME`

All you have to do then is:

- remove any unencrypted copies of the app from the system
- **explicitly** inform your user to unmount the DMG when he's done using the app (or script this to do it automatically)
- explain to your fellow StackOverflowers what the actual issue is that you're solving. Msw has a point and I hope you can elaborate a bit.

Comment: The thing is that the user im writing this for is not a programmer and knows little about computers. I want to provide an interface whereby he double clicks on an exe and a prompt comes up asking for a password and only runs the executable if the password is correct. Almost as though I did as msw suggests but somehow embed the current executable within my own.

Comment: So who are you trying to protect the application against? Security questions are meaningless without an answer to that question. You say the user is not computer savvy but has root access. Are you trying to protect him from access to your application? I hope not, because he has already authenticated himself to the OS so has unlimited privilege and your extra hurdle will just annoy. Are you trying to protect against someone who has access to root's login session but is not ignorant? Then she already has access and another password won't stop her.

Comment: This is almost a solution, can I programmatically unmount the disk when the application exits? I.e. can I (to use C# terms) suscribe to the event of the application quitting and use that to unmount the volume?

Comment: I've updated my answer to address that issue (or at least give a hint). Good luck with this.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously with this set-up nothing's going to be 100% secure, but for casual users you can encrypt the application with the password, then write a launching application that decrypts and launches the application when the password is entered, and deletes the application when it quits.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char buf[BUFSIZ]
puts('what is the secret password? ');
fgets(buf, BUFSIZ, stdin);
if (strcmp('secret', buf)) exit(1);
```

Should work as well as anything else you might code, and has the advantage of simplicity and portability.

Comment: There's an old question on SO that has a lot of answers in the same line: use words that are commonly used/found in an executable, so searching the binary produces lots of matches, etc... I can't seem to find it right now

Comment: As I said, I cannot embed code into the program as I did not write the program. That is, unless you know how to embed code into an existing executable.